# python (jython) archiving library

Tags: java, python, jython, archive

Is there a neat archiving library that automatically handles archiving a folder or directories for you out there?
I am using Jython, so Java libs are also open for use.
-UPDATE-
Also Im looking for timestamp archiving. ie

archive-dir/2008/11/16/zipfilebypreference.zip

then the next day call it again and it creates another folder.
Im sure there is something out there on the internet, who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have either the:

- [gzip library](http://www.xhaus.com/alan/python/httpcomp.html) used here in a Jython servlet:

```
import  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

import  cStringIO
import  gzip
import  string

def compressBuf(buf):
    zbuf = cStringIO.StringIO()
    zfile = gzip.GzipFile(mode = 'wb',  fileobj = zbuf, compresslevel = 6)
    zfile.write(buf)
    zfile.close()
    return zbuf.getvalue()
```

- or the direct used of java.util.zip as illustrated [here](https://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds6-3/ovp63.html), for one file, or for a all directory content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.zip, when I was using Jython the built in zip library in python didn't work